# how to split string and convert to integer

Tags: python, string

```
numbers = "51-52"
for st in numbers:
    part = st.split("-")
    print(part)
```

this is my code so far.

*My results*:['5']['1']['', '']['5']['2']

*Expected*:['51']['52']

Comment: Your code and your result do not match. It must be  `numbers = "51-52" ` to get your output.

Comment: i said it's a string

Comment: Do you realize that your expected result is not a valid Python value? Do you want that expected to just be printed, or did you mean something like `['51', '52]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
numbers = "51-52"
part = [int(x) for x in numbers.split("-")]
print(part)
```

Comment: although more useful, the original question wants a list of string.

Answer (score 1):

because it should be just:

```
numbers = "51-52"
print numbers.split("-")
```

Answer (score 0):

`for st in numbers` will iterate through each character in the string, so you end up with each character separate in the resulting set. Leave that out and simply

```
numbers = "51-52"
parts = numbers.split("-")
print(parts)
```